# How to update multiple columns from different table of MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I am using MariaDB. I am trying to update two columns from SELECT different table.

```
UPDATE User U
SET 
    U.UserPoint = (
        SELECT  ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM CARD_COMM R
                WHERE R.Card_ID = C.Card_ID) * 3
                +
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM SECTION_CARD_LIKE L
                WHERE L.Card_ID = C.Card_ID) * 1) as userPoint
                FROM CARD C WHERE C.userid = U.userid ORDER BY userPoint DESC limit 1 )
```

this works

```
UPDATE User U
SET 
    (U.UserPoint, U.Card) = (
        SELECT  ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM CARD_COMM R
                WHERE R.Card_ID = C.Card_ID) * 3
                +
                (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM SECTION_CARD_LIKE L
                WHERE L.Card_ID = C.Card_ID) * 1) as userPoint,
                C.Card_ID as card
                FROM CARD C WHERE C.userid = U.userid ORDER BY userPoint DESC limit 1 )
```

but this dose not....

How do I do this??
please help me...

Comment: Not sure what you want to do?! In first example you insert a single value in one column. In 2nd example you try the same, but specify two columns but only one value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a multi-table update, something like

```
UPDATE User
    JOIN ( SELECT userid, up_value, card_value ... ) AS x
        ON x.userid = User.userid
    SET User.UserPoint = x.up_value,
        User.Card = x.card_value;
```

(With suitable expressions/subqueries/etc for up_value & card_value)

You seem to be updating all rows in User??